# Слушатель на элемент в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, activity, android-navigation-drawer

Мне нужно сделать слушатель нажатия на item в Navigation Drawer. Я сделал выезжающее из левого края Navigation Drawer, поместил туда items. Теперь мне надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на item, я мог перейти на другой activity в моём проекте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы создавали меню средствами `Android Studio` то значит все необходимые функции у вас уже созданы. При создании менюшки вам нужно было указать ее имя, поэтому вы переходите в класс с таким названием, которое вы указали при создании. Дальше вам нужно найти в этом классе такой метод:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected
```

этот метод отвечает за выбор нужного пункта меню, и дальше вы просто делаете переходы на нужные активити, при выборе определенного пункта меню. Вот как у меня в проекте выглядит такой выбор:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
f (id == R.id.received) {
try {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} else if (id == R.id.outcome) {
try {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, messageList).commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} else if (id == R.id.draft) {
try {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,messageList).commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}
```

и по поводу переходов на нужные вам активити - я вам посоветую использовать фрагменты вместо активити, потому-что они легче для обработки.

Надеюсь я чем-то помог в вашем вопросе. Если будет что-то не понятно, не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте. Я верю что у вас получится, удачи :)

Comment: А если я создал NAvigation Drawer с помощью Navigation View?

Comment: что значит с помощью `Navigation View`? я честно говоря первый раз слышу такой способ :)

Comment: Вместо Relative Layout делал Drawer Layout, и помещал туда Navigation View

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS92bq3XxkA - по этому гайду

Comment: менюшку вы я так понял тоже сами делали? ну если смотреть по видео

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: на 8 минуте идет создание самого списка меню, я до конца досмотрел, там к сожалению нету того что вам нужно, сейчас здесь буду показывать походу)) так вы создали список?

Comment: Да, я сделал menu, и там есть navigation_menu, в котором есть items

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83433/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-).